# How to record remote video using webrtc or media stream from video tag

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc

Hi I am using webrtc to setup one2one video call.I can able to record local video but not remote video.I want to record remote video.Please help!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) or [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) or MediaRecorder API to record local and/or remote videos.

For remote video, there are two options:

1. Record video from `peer.onaddstream` event
2. Record video from a `<video>` tag using `captureStream` API

First one is VERY_Easy however it you MUST have access to javascript codes.

The second option is also easy through this chrome extension:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recordrtc/ndcljioonkecdnaaihodjgiliohngojp  ( [Open Sourced here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/screen-recording) )

`captureStream` API are supported both on Chrome `>=53` and Firefox.

Chrome, however, still requires this flag: `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`

If you enable above flag, restart chrome, and right click over any video (on any webpage), you will be able to record that video. (whether it is WebRTC video, mp4 or webm file or HLS/DASH live stream)

Here is the basic concept of the above extension:

```
var streamFromVideoTag = videoTag.captureStream(15); // 15 is frame-rates
var recorder = RecordRTC(streamFromVideoTag, {type: 'video'});
```

For `onaddstream` event option:

```
var recorder;
peer.onaddstream = function(event) {
   var streamToBeRecorded = event.stream;
   recorder = RecordRTC(streamToBeRecorded, {type: 'video'});
   recorder.startRecording();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible places to record the video

1. **Locally**: Personally I believe is a bad idea because of browser's limited storage capacity. If this is fine, then we can go ahead with [RecordRtc](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) OR [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder)
2. **Remote at the server** : This is a better option. It can record the participant's video at the server. There are ways to do that. One way, which I have tried out is Kurento. It has both Java and node.js implementations with examples. [Example](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/js/tutorial-recorder.html)